# Rake runs function twice

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I started creating a set of Rake tasks (my first time, with limited Ruby experience) and when I run the first task, using either `rake test` or `rake db`, from the command line I get two outputs even though there is only one file in the directory in question.

rakefile.rb

```
require 'fileutils'

FILES    = ["html", "css", "js", "svg", "otf", "eot", "ttf", "woff", "jpeg", "map", "ico", "map", "png", "db"]

desc 'test script'
task :test => [:db]

task :db do
    copy_to 'data/', 'c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/data'
end

def copy_to(dest, src)

    files = FileList.new()
    files.include Dir.glob("#{src}/*.*")
    FILES.each {|ext| files.include "#{src}/*.#{ext}"}
    files.each do |src|
        puts "copying: #{src} to #{dest}"
        FileUtils.cp src, dest
    end

end
```

Output

```
(in C:/xampp/htdocs/home/gateway)                        
copying: c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/data/foo.db to data/   
copying: c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/data/foo.db to data/
```

When I do `rake -T` I get the following (which is what I would expect):

```
(in C:/xampp/htdocs/home/gateway)
rake test  # test script
```

Of course `foo.db` only gets copied once, or the second copy overwrites the 
first one.

**EDIT** ran `rake test --trace` from the command line

```
** Invoke test (first_time)                                                   
** Invoke db (first_time)                                                     
** Execute db                                                                 
copying: c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/data/foo.db to data/ 
copying: c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/data/foo.db to data/ 
** Execute test
```

Is it executing `:db` and *then* `:test`? Or is `:db` running twice as it appears to be doing here? What am I missing? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding `foo.db` to the `files` FileList twice:

```
files.include Dir.glob("#{src}/*.*")
FILES.each {|ext| files.include "#{src}/*.#{ext}"}
```

Because `FILES` (which is a misleading variable name) includes `"db"`, on the first line you're adding `*.*` to `files` and on the second line you're adding `*.db` to `files`.

It's not clear why you have both lines, since the first line will add every file in the directory, so the second line is only going to add files that you've already added.

Comment: *smacks forehead* I totally missed that @Jordan. I was thinking I would limit the extensions of the files that could be included, so I'll rewrite and do that only one time. I'll also rename the variable to reflect that it is file extensions.